# hyperef with adhoc theorem numbering chapter-number

Tags: hyperref, numbering

I'm trying to use the label/ref mechanism to get a numbering chapter.nb of my theorems. I get the numbering correct, but the hyperref link goes to the wrong address: it forgets the "chapter" part, so "2.1" goes to (thm number) "1" and the first such instance is "1.1".
I kept fancyhdr and mdframed in the ECM in case it influences a solution.

Many thanks for your time and advice!
Best, Olivier

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, mdframed, hyperref}
\newcounter{mythmcnt}
\setcounter{mythmcnt}{0}
\renewcommand*\themythmcnt{\thechapter.\arabic{mythmcnt}}
\newmdenv{ispecialthm}
\newenvironment{thmenvN}[2][]{\refstepcounter{mythmcnt}%
\begingroup\begin{ispecialthm}[frametitle={#2\ \themythmcnt}]}{\end{ispecialthm}\endgroup}

\newenvironment{thmN}[1][]{\begingroup\begin{thmenvN}[#1]{Theorem}}{\end{thmenvN}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\setcounter{mythmcnt}{0}

\begin{thmN}
  \label{thm1} A first theorem.
\end{thmN}

Here are Theorem~\ref{thm1} and Theorem~\ref{thm2}.

\chapter{Second}
\setcounter{mythmcnt}{0}

\begin{thmN}
  \label{thm2} A second theorem.
\end{thmN}

Here are Theorem~\ref{thm1} and Theorem~\ref{thm2}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Check the log file. It already mentions that the hyperref target is no uniq.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand\theHmythmcnt{\arabic{mythmcnt}.\thepage}` on order to make the target hyperref uses more uniq

Comment: Many thanks, that works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Just define `mythmcnt` to be subordinate to `chapter`.

I also removed redundant grouping. However, there are parts that get unused.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, mdframed, hyperref}

\newcounter{mythmcnt}[chapter]
\renewcommand*\themythmcnt{\thechapter.\arabic{mythmcnt}}

\newmdenv{ispecialthm}

\newenvironment{thmenvN}[2][]
  {%
   \refstepcounter{mythmcnt}%
   \ispecialthm[frametitle={#2\ \themythmcnt}]%
  }
  {\endispecialthm}

\newenvironment{thmN}[1][]
  {\thmenvN[#1]{Theorem}}
  {\endthmenvN}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\begin{thmN}[abc]
  \label{thm1} A first theorem.
\end{thmN}

Here are Theorem~\ref{thm1} and Theorem~\ref{thm2}.

\chapter{Second}

\begin{thmN}
  \label{thm2} A second theorem.
\end{thmN}

Here are Theorem~\ref{thm1} and Theorem~\ref{thm2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that! And for the cleaning of my 'code':) Can you explain a bit why you define \printifnotempty ? Olivier

Comment: @OlivierRamaré That was for the second argument, but I realized you don't really use it like I thought. Remove.